# WCF secured with Azure AD

Tags: winforms, azure, wcf, oauth-2.0, odata

I have a WCF service hosted by Azure and secured by Azure AD. when I use the web to access the service I am prompted with the Azure login,after a successful login,I reach the data. I am trying to access the data form Winforms, I reach the OAuth2 login screen, I successfully login and get the token. I add the token to the context headers, but still receive this message:
 `InnerException = "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."`

any help on how to access WCF secured with Azure AD, from Winforms ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this error and it's hard to guess. 
But here are few things to check.

- Your client application (Winform) is registered with Azure AD and has
  permission to access your web app. Make sure desktop/mobile apps have 
  to be registered wtih Azure AD as native app.
- Your Audience is set correctly in Azure AD . I have seen many people 
  struggle if they don't have it set properly.
- If your WCF is hosted in app services then turn on the real time logging. Go to app services and turn on the "Diagnostic logs".Under "Diagnostic logs" set the "application log" to verbose.  After this go to "Log Stream" in app service to view the real time app logging. Now if you hit your web app with your client you should be able to see the why are you getting 401 unauthorized.

Hope that helps !

Comment: this is the log I get:2018-12-04T08:40:25  PID[15328] Verbose     Received request: GET https://electionswcf.azurewebsites.net/WcfDataService1.svc/Voters()?$top=100
2018-12-04T08:40:25  PID[15328] Warning     JWT validation failed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://electionswcf.azurewebsites.net'. Did not match:  validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'a9971017-5834-4943-998c-c6c8867c28e7' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'https://electionswcf.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback'.

Comment: THANKS for your help

Comment: Yes this is audience mismatch. Did you activated Authentication / Authorization in App services Secured by Azure AD?

Comment: Do you know a better way to write a winform which consume data from secured WCF?

Comment: Yes I activated Authentication / Authorization in App services

Comment: In Authentication / Authorization under "authentication provider" click azure AD. You might be using express mode which is set by default. Click the advance and at the bottom you would see "Allowed Token Audience" . Just add your wcf base url (https: //electionswcf.azurewebsites.net ) there, and don't forget to save the settings on the main screen. it should be good now. You can now switch back the AD mode to express and service should continue working.

Comment: still the same problem, I will try to delete everything and start from the begging. What I want to do is access a SQL database hosted on azure sql server from winforms. I have build a WCF and I can access the data. now I want to secure it, any suggestion on how to do it? I am looking for the easiest way and most modern, THANKS for you help.

Comment: Just wondering why you need WCF to access data in winform ? Can't you access it directly from SQL using connection string?

Comment: yes I can, but the SQL server is hosted on Azure and I need my Winform to access it securely from anywhere. I can do it using a connection string but that means I will save and transfer the user name and password insecurely. Also this mean that I need to turn OFF the SQL server firewall.

Comment: ok. you don't need wcf then. use asp.net core web api. deploy on azure app services and use managed service identity to securely access your sql from app service. turn the authorization on and access web api from winform client as discussed above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try. Do you have any examples?

Comment: check for official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio