# 401 Unauthorized while accessing azure function with bearer token | function app is secured with AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have a simple function app with HTTP trigger:
[Function app code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKoGv.png)

I have authorized my function app with AAD. I am able to get the access token successfully from v2 token url https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENENT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

In scope I am passing the Application ID URI from app registration.

[Access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg611.png)

But when I am trying to pass the access token in header while invoking function app url, I am getting 401.
[401 postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mrmd.png)

Not sure what I am missing. Please help

Comment: @StanleyGong, nope, it is still there. I already tried your solution previously, but no luck.
What exactly I need to pass in scope?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763205/how-to-secure-azure-functions-with-oauth-for-both-humans-and-machines/58795499#58795499) would be helpful. Let me know if you have any more questions.

If this solution does not work for you,and `scope` param is necessary for you, I have checked your post, seems everything is right. I assume it is due to Auth config ,could you pls have a check?Go to Azure function => Auth => identity provider => find your app => Edit.

I'll share my config and steps to call function below:

My config:
[image]

The way I get the access token :
[image]

Not bring token:
[image]

Use this token to call Azure function :

[image]

Comment: I have exactly same steps and I still get 401 unauthorised in postman