# Use PowerShell with OAuth Token for HTTP Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, oauth, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which has authentication enabled and set to require an identity provider:

App Service authentication: Enabled
Restrict access: Require authentication
Unauthenticated requests: Return HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Token store: Enabled

Identity provider - App (client) ID
(Name of App Removed): Client ID Removed
Client Secret Setting Name: Microsoft_Provider_Authentication_Secret

[image]

When I use Power Automate to POST to the HTTP function it works. This tells me the security is set up and working as expected. When I try and POST to the function directly from PowerShell using my desktop, I get a 401 unauthorized.  This is a GCCH environment.

This is the PowerShell code where I get an oath token and am trying to use that to POST to the HTTP function.  I tried using the HTTP URL with and without the 'code=' and neither worked.

```
#These URLs are used to access get the token; scope has not been required is uses the app ID 
    $loginURL   = "https://login.microsoftonline.us"
    $resource   = "https://graph.microsoft.us"
    $Tenant      = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.us"
    $ClientID = "removed"
    $Secret="removed"
    $fcnKey = "removed"
    $fcnURL = "https://removed?"   #Azure function url without the code at the end

    $AuthBody = @{
        grant_type="client_credentials";
        resource=$resource;
        client_id=$ClientID;
        client_secret=$Secret}

    $Oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $loginURL/$Tenant/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body
    $AuthBody -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    $AuthToken = @{
        'Authorization'="$($Oauth.token_type) $($Oauth.access_token)";
        'Content-Type' = "application/json";
        'x-functions-key' = $fcnkey;}

    #This returns a 401 unauthorized
    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $AuthToken -Uri $fcnURL -Method POST

    #This also returns a 401 unauthorized
    $AuthToken = @{
        'Authorization'="$($Oauth.token_type) $($Oauth.access_token)";
        'Content-Type' = "application/json";}

    $FullURL = "https://removed?code=removed"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $AuthToken -Uri $fullURL -Method POST
```

Comment: What type of authentication is being used.  Working code is probably trying more than one type.  You are probably using wrong type.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows

Answer (score 0):

As @*jdweng* suggested to check the type of authentication and the process of authorization in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) of Azure AD Authentication Flows.

**Check if the below steps help to fix the issue**:

- Make Sure you entered the "App ID URI" in the "Allowed Token Audiences" Box.
- Same App ID URI should be used for acquiring the token.
- Refer to the Similar issue-solutions where 401 Unauthorized error is registered on enabling the App service Authentication on Azure Function App such as MSQ&A[337577](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/337577/azure-function-returns-401-unauthorized-after-app), SO Questions [67957353](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67957742) and [55226143](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55226143).